# Windows won't open my computer after failed iPhone backup

Tags: windows-8.1, backup, itunes, iphone, icloud

The story in a nutshell is as follows - My Iphone (iOS 8.2) had some 7k photos on it. I used Windows 8.1 function of moving all photos to the computer, and I checked the box of "erase when copied".

During this very long transfer, windows turned to "sleep mode", and after I woke it up - the transfer got stuck!

My original thought was to get back to business, but things got nasty. When iPhone is connected with USB, I can't even open "My Computer" On windows, it get stuck, and can only open when the iPhone is not connected. This has never happened before the failed files transfer.

How can I complete this backup and go back to normal?

Comment: Try rebooting the computer and iPhone.

Comment: When they are not connected ...